# How to generate oauth token using user key & secret

Tags: rest, oauth

I am trying to get data from a REST API, they have not fully implemented OAuth. They are only using the signature methodology that OAuth uses once you already have an access token.
I have been provided with consumer key & secret PLUS User Key & Secret.
Now I am not sure how to generate oauth token using user key & secret.

Can you please suggest how to do it ?

Comment: What technology are you using (Java, C#, Javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the [OAuth.net site](http://oauth.net/code/), they have a code section which points you to several frameworks for a variety of languages to implement OAuth. Most, if not all, of the frameworks have examples which you can follow to understand how to setup your OAuth calls with their framework.